# Set MySQL Variables with MySQLi (not PHP variables)

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli, set

It's work with PHP variables:

Prepearing one result from query function

```
   extract($GLOBALS);
   $GLOBALS['mysqli'] = $mysqli;

function select($a,$b){
    $mysqli = $GLOBALS['mysqli'];

    $query = $mysqli -> query($b);
       while($row = ($query -> fetch_assoc())){
        return $row[$a]."<br>";
        }// while
    $query -> free();       
    }
```

order from where clicked

```
$self = "SELECT order FROM channels WHERE id='$id'";
$self = "(SELECT order FROM (($self)AS x))";

    if($btn == "Up"){
    // Order previows
    $other = "SELECT MAX(order) FROM channels WHERE order < $self";
        }
    if($btn == "Down"){
    // Order next
    $other = "SELECT MIN(order) FROM channels WHERE order > $self";
        }

$other = "SELECT order FROM channels WHERE order=($other)";
```

SET PHP VARIABLE INSTEAD OF MYSQL VARIABLE
    $other = select('order',$other);

```
$query = "UPDATE channels SET order=$self WHERE order='$other';";
$query .= "UPDATE channels SET order='$other' WHERE id='$id'";

$mysqli->multi_query($query);
```

### The problem? I need a faster query using one MySQL query

This doesnt' work:

SET MYSQL VARIABLE INSTEAD O PHP VARIABLE

```
$query = "DEFINE other INT;"; // return: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFINE other INT(...);
$query .= "DECLARE other INT;"; // return: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE other INT(...);
$query .= "SET other = $other;"; // return: Unknown system variable 'other'
$query .= "UPDATE channels SET order=$self WHERE order=other;";
$query .= "UPDATE channels SET order=other WHERE id='$id'";

$mysqli->multi_query($query);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got to use a [user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html):

> **User-Defined Variables**
>
> You can store a value in a user-defined variable in one statement and
>   then refer to it later in another statement. This enables you to pass
>   values from one statement to another. User-defined variables are
>   session-specific. That is, a user variable defined by one client
>   cannot be seen or used by other clients. All variables for a given
>   client session are automatically freed when that client exits.
>
> User variables are written as **@var_name**, where the variable name
>   var_name consists of alphanumeric characters, “.”, “_”, and “$”. A
>   user variable name can contain other characters if you quote it as a
>   string or identifier (for example, @'my-var', @"my-var", or
>   @`my-var`).

```
$query .= "SET @other = $other;"; // return: Unknown system variable 'other'
```

Comment: So the entire line maight be like this?
$query = "SET @other = $other;"; 
$query .= "UPDATE channels SET order=$self WHERE order=@other;";
$query .= "UPDATE channels SET order=@other WHERE id='$id'";

$mysqli->multi_query($query);