# Using MySQL variables in outside stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, stored-procedures

I am trying to learn how to use variables in MySQL:

```
$query = "
    SET @myid = '1234';
    SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = @myid;
";
```

But I get a syntax error on line 1.

- I have looked at the manual and it states this is the correct syntax.
- I have also scoured stack but most of the questions are based on
  store procedures.

Are MySQL variables limited to stored procedures only? If not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't run multiple queries in a single `query()` call. that's all. issue `query("set...")` and `query("select ...")` instead.

Comment: can you show us the code you are using to execute this sql, are you using mysqli, pdo ?

Comment: Its just mysqli, looking at the manual again Marc's comment makes sense as the examples I was following are from a terminal https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: could be good for others to see it when you are done Edward, as an answer yourself

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php to execute both. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853684/set-mysql-variables-with-mysqli-not-php-variables

Comment: @Drew I might just do that!

Answer (score 0):

## Using mysqli_multi_query()

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php
- [Cannot figure out how to run a mysqli_multi_query and use the results from the last query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667596/cannot-figure-out-how-to-run-a-mysqli-multi-query-and-use-the-results-from-the-l)

Trying to use variables inline with queries throws a syntax error on line 1. **Thank you Marc B.**

```
SET @myid = '<?php echo $myid; ?>';
SELECT t.*,
    CASE WHEN m.`dob` BETWEEN @uDateStart AND @uDateEnd
    etc...
```

My solution was to use `mysqli::multi_query` or `mysqli_multi_query` like so:

```
$this -> db -> multi_query($sql);
$i = 0;
$querySelect = 1; //query 1
do{
    if($result = $this -> db -> store_result()) {
        if($i === $querySelect) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
    $i++;
} while($this -> db -> more_results() && $this -> db -> next_result());
```

`$querySelect` prevents returning unwanted result sets.